# Is it possible to clear an individual APN from the notification center as it is for a local notification

Tags: ios

If my app queues several local notifications, then after they are expired they will appear in the notification center history list (assuming the user hasn't disabled it of course).

When the user selects one of these notifications my app is able to delete that particular notification from the notification center.

I would like to be able to do the same thing with APNs, is this possible?

Comment: How do you delete one specific notification from the notification center?